# How add Custom Babel Config to storybook ( 6 - 7 version )

Tags: reactjs, next.js, storybook, nx-monorepo

I have a Next.js application integrated into an NX monorepo. When attempting to run Storybook for this application using `nx run shop:storybook`, Storybook tries to locate the `.babelrc` file in the root directory of the `"shop"` project. However, it can't find it and throws an error.

Storybook expects to find a `.babelrc` file with this configuration:

```
{
  "presets": ["@nrwl/react/babel"],
  "plugins": []
}
```

When I add this file, Storybook runs without issues. But the application itself fails to start because Next.js requires a `.babelrc` config like this:

```
{
  "presets": ["next/babel"],
  "plugins": []
}
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't accept a configuration with "@nrwl/react/babel"

This leads to a conflict where I can run either Storybook or the application, but not both, due to the incompatible **.babelrc** configurations.

I've considered the option of instructing Storybook to search for the .babelrc file from a different location, but I'm unsure how to implement this solution.

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  // ...
  webpackFinal: async (config, { configType }) => {
    // ...
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          configFile: path.resolve(__dirname, '../path/to/storybook/.babelrc'), 
        },
      },
    });
    // ...
    return config;
  },
};
```

**So how to tell storybook use custom .babelrc but not one that is in the project root???**

It also says that we can placed .babelrc in .storybook folder and it should be used from there, but it also doesn't work.
https://v4-0-10--storybooks.netlify.app/configurations/custom-babel-config/

( I'm using version 12 of Next.js. )

Comment: did you ever found how to?